# Saving Files c# - without overwriting?

Tags: c#, file-io, save

I am saving data to a file every 60 secs, I have it saving every 60 secs ok but it deletes the previous data added. Is there a way in which it would add to the file rather than overwrite it. And without using save dialog as it is done in the background.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not write in append mode so that it appends instead of overwriting?

Comment: could you provide more information? a code sample would be of great help. Shot in the blue: use `FileMode.Append` instead of `Create`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems opening the File in Append mode will solve your problem.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zc0w663.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\somefile.txt", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Hello line..");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify `FileMode.Append` in the `FileStream` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use `File` class `AppendText` method.

```
StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("D:\\Text.txt");
sw.WriteLine("Hello");
sw.WriteLine("World");
sw.WriteLine("Test");
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StreamWriter` with `append` as `true` in the constructor.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

OK as i am getting your question You are having a File And you want to save new data on that instead of replacing it

You can just open its content using stream reader.and append that data you want to insert on the file 
using writer don't save file each time just append data on that file so when you just appending something on that it will not overwrite that file.